# Speeds of objects in center of mass frame in an elastic collision

Tags: mass, energy-conservation, momentum, collision, speed

I have been working on an elastic 1-d collision problem of two objects of different mass. I noticed that their speeds in the cm frame are the same after and before the collision. Does that also hold in more than 1d collisions ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the center of mass frame of reference the total linear momentum of two colliding objects must me zero. Thus $$m_1 \vec v_1=-m_2 \vec v_2$$ before and after the collision. This means that also in the case of 2 or 3 spatial dimensions the velocity vectors are always parallel but in opposite directions. If primed velcocities are the velocities after the collision, the energy conservation requires $$ m_1v_1^2+m_2v_2^2=m_1v_1^{'2}+m_2v_2^{'2}$$ Inserting $v_2=\frac{m_1v_1}{m_2}$ and $v_2^{'}=\frac{m_1v_1{'}}{m_2}$ into the energy conservation equation yields $$v_1^2=v_1^{'2}$$ and doing the same for $v_1$ and $v_1^{'}$ $$v_2^2=v_2^{'2}$$ Therefore, after the collision, for each mass the magnitude of velocity is the same as before the collision and the direction is opposite. This holds, indeed, for collisions in 1, 2 and 3 spatial dimensions.